# Nvidia X server settings

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I got this message. Anybody can help?

> You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X
>   configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart
>   the X server.

Comment: did you try to run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`?

Comment: It says command not found and i can't get this out. Wats wrong?

Comment: dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-common                                1:0.2.44.2                                       Find obsolete NVIDIA drivers

Comment: try to purge the old drivers and install them new, may be never ones like 310 or 313. What Ubuntu Version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Can somebody help please give me the command to install my nvidia GT525M. I will uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 and reinstall it again by using the new command. Hope you are an expert. :) Thanks!